# Can a button handle multiple actions?

Tags: javascript

guys I am just wondering whether it's possible or not for a button to handle more than one action, for example, I want to show questions on a quiz app every time I click on the Next button
FYI I am using javascript only

Comment: you can handle 1 action (function) that does multiple things

Comment: would you clear it out a little bit, please?

Comment: What duxfox means is that e.g your button's onclick will always call ClickMe(); but inside your ClickMe function, you can perform multiple actions using if-else based on e.g a radio button, checkbox, any other user input

Comment: Yes, but you have to write conditional code within the EventListener, with a reference to one or more higher scoped variables.

Comment: I've been trying to accomplish what you've said but it didn't work out well with me, Is it possible to give me examples on that please ?